# How to write shell script to get the pod status of kubernetes cluster

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, awk, grep

In my k8 cluster I have pods running that the pod name contains the word "inventory" (actually 2pods with this name)
I need to write a shell script to delete deployment and re-deploy and then it should check the specific pod is running or not and then display a message.
Here is what I tried.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /apps/application/application_yamls_develop/deployment-artifacts/inventory-service
kubectl delete -f inventory-service.yaml -n back-end
kubectl apply -f inventory-service.yaml -n back-end
sleep 20

pod_name="inventory"
namespace="back-end"

# Get the pod status
pod_status=$(kubectl get pods -n "$namespace" -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.name.includes('$pod_name'))].status.phase}")

# Check if any matching pod is running
if [[ -n "$pod_status" ]]; then
  echo "Pod running"
else
  echo "Pod not running"
fi
```

But this is giving the bellow error.

```
error: error parsing jsonpath {.items[?(@.metadata.name.includes('inventory'))].status.phase}, unclosed array expect ]
```

Can someone please pointout the issue.

Thanks..!

Comment: Did you forget to set namespace, or it's default?

Comment: @Ivan Thanks..I completely forgot that. I modified the code. But the issue still the same

Comment: Well if you doing it exactly like this: `kubectl get pods -n "namespace" -o jsonpath...` It'll obviously fail, it should be: `kubectl get pods -n "$namespace" -o jsonpath...`

Comment: @Ivan Oh that was a typo in the question .. Corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```html
#!/bin/bash

pod_name="devopslk"
namespace="devops"

# Get the pod status
pod_status=$(kubectl get pod "$pod_name" -n "$namespace" -o jsonpath='{.status.phase}')

# Check if any matching pod is running
if [[ -n "$pod_status" ]]; then
  echo "Pod running"
else
  echo "Pod not running, Current status: $pod_status"
fi
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Arshad,Thank you for the answer.. This works if we know the pod name exactly. But the pod name changes with id's when restarting, Ex- inventory-7cbd497897-g4hz9.... So when checking the pod status somewhere it should go trough a contains logic for the sub-string

Answer (score 1):

Found answer in k8s [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

```
# kubectl does not support regular expressions for JSONpath output
# The following command does not work
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.name=~/^test$/)].metadata.name}'

# The following command achieves the desired result
kubectl get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name | test("test-")).spec.containers[].image'
```

And partial name in filter statement won't work also you have to set full pod name here:

```
$ k -n $ns get po -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.name=="test")].metadata.name}'

$ k -n $ns get po -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.name=="test-56b87dd7dc-4fcwn")].metadata.name}' 
test-56b87dd7dc-4fcwn
```

So first you need to get all pods and grep them some how to get the needed pod and than check it status. Or use `jq` as suggested in k8s docs.

Or get names and statuses at the same time:

```
    $ k -n $ns get po -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}[{.metadata.name},{.status.phase}]{'\n'}{end}" |\
    grep -Ei ".*$pod_name.*running" || echo fail
```

And then again grep needed pod and you'll get the status.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using pod label as specified in below script(modified accordingly which is provided by you)

```
#!/bin/bash
#Namespace Name
namespace="backend"
#Provide label name which is specified in pod definition
appname="inventory"

# Get the pod name
pod_name=$(kubectl get pod -n $namespace -l app=$appname -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}")

# Get the pod status
pod_status=$(kubectl get pods -n $namespace -o=jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.name == '$pod_name')].status.phase}")

# Check if any matching pod is running
if [[ ! -z "$pod_status" ]]; then
  echo "Pod running"
else
  echo "Pod not running"
fi
```